# Getting a syntax error when trying to execute this SQL query in Python

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to get the script to automatically set the query start time as 6am yesterday (and will set the end time as 6am today once I figure out the Start time error) but I am getting a syntax error (102, b"Incorrect syntax near '06'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n").

If I take out the """+StartTime+""" and change to '20211212 07:00:00.000' then it works but I need a way for the script to keep track of the current date rather than going back and changing every day.

```
from datetime import timedelta
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame 
import pandas as pd
import pymssql


from datetime import date, timedelta
today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)

BEGINDATE=yesterday
ENDDATE=today
BEGINDATE=BEGINDATE.strftime("%Y%m%d")
ENDDATE=ENDDATE.strftime("%Y%m%d")
StartTime = BEGINDATE +' 06:00:00:000'
print(StartTime)

Query= """SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime
SET @StartDate = """+StartTime+"""
SET @EndDate = '20211213 07:00:00.000'
SET NOCOUNT OFF
SELECT temp.TagName ,DateTime ,Value ,vValue ,MinRaw = ISNULL(Cast(AnalogTag.MinRaw as VarChar(20)),'N/A') ,MaxRaw = ISNULL(Cast(AnalogTag.MaxRaw as VarChar(20)),'N/A') ,Unit = ISNULL(Cast(EngineeringUnit.Unit as VarChar(20)),'N/A') ,StartDateTime From (
    SELECT  * 
     FROM History
     WHERE History.TagName IN ('S03_FT03_04_TOT01')
     AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic'
     AND wwCycleCount = 1440
     AND wwVersion = 'Latest'
     AND DateTime >= @StartDate
     AND DateTime <= @EndDate) temp
LEFT JOIN AnalogTag ON AnalogTag.TagName =temp.TagName
LEFT JOIN EngineeringUnit ON AnalogTag.EUKey = EngineeringUnit.EUKey
 WHERE temp.StartDateTime >= @StartDate"""
cur.execute(Query)
print(Query)
```

Comment: You are missing quotation marks around your `StartTime`.

Comment: @KlausD. Inside the Query? Is it not supposed to be left outside the quotes as it's a variable?

Comment: Print out the `Query` before executing it and compare the `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` lines.

Comment: Ah gotcha, it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider running parameterization in Python passed into a prepared SQL statement without declaring `@` params. Also, keep all variables in datetimes without any string conversion.

Not quite sure what your date ranges require given 6 AM and 7 AM confusion, below calculates range from yesterday at 6 AM to today at 5:59:59 AM (for 24 hours). Adjust as needed. Finally, final `WHERE` is moved into subquery.

```py
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame 
import pandas as pd
import pymssql

BEGINDATE = datetime.combine(
    date.today() - timedelta(days = 1), datetime.min.time()
) + timedelta(hours = 6)
print(BEGINDATE)
# 2021-12-12 06:00:00

ENDDATE = BEGINDATE + timedelta(days = 1) - timedelta(seconds=1)
print(ENDDATE)
# 2021-12-13 05:59:59

### PREPARED STATEMENT WITH %s PLACEHOLDERS
Query= """SELECT temp.TagName 
                , [DateTime] 
                , [Value] 
                , vValue  
                , MinRaw = ISNULL(CAST(AnalogTag.MinRaw AS VARCHAR(20)), 'N/A')
                , MaxRaw = ISNULL(CAST(AnalogTag.MaxRaw AS VARCHAR(20)), 'N/A') 
                , Unit = ISNULL(CAST(EngineeringUnit.Unit AS VARCHAR(20)), 'N/A')
                , StartDateTime 
          FROM (
              SELECT  * 
              FROM History
              WHERE History.TagName IN ('S03_FT03_04_TOT01')
                AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic'
                AND wwCycleCount = 1440
                AND wwVersion = 'Latest'
                AND [DateTime] >= %s
                AND [DateTime] <= %s
                AND StartDateTime >= %s
          ) temp
          LEFT JOIN AnalogTag ON AnalogTag.TagName = temp.TagName
          LEFT JOIN EngineeringUnit ON AnalogTag.EUKey = EngineeringUnit.EUKey
       """

# RUN QUERY WITH PARAMETERS
cur.execute(Query, [BEGINDATE, ENDDATE, BEGINDATE])
print(Query)
```